# Python: How to match a specific word in a list of strings, no matter it consists of upper or lower letters

Tags: python, find

I would like to define a function that:

- takes as input a list consisted by strings and a keyword
- returns a new list with the index numbers of the strings in that contains the keyword, no matter that one or more characters of the keyword are lower or upper.

I have tried this:

```
def find_the_word(doc_list, keyword):
   index_list = [doc_list.index(element) for element in doc_list if keyword in element]
   return index_list
```

For input of `a` and `'name'` I would like to take as a result `[0,1,2]`.

```
a = ["My name is Maria.", "What is your name?", "Name three european countries."]
find_the_word(a,'name')
```

Comment: what have you tried to solve the problem with upper vs lowercase letters? for example, `str.lower()`?

Comment: To handle edge cases use `str.casefold()`

Comment: However, you're wider problem statement is still not entirely clear to me

Comment: Another alternative, use lowercase.  Your function should look like : 
```def find_the_word(doc_list, keyword):
   index_list = [doc_list.index(element) for element in doc_list if keyword.lower() in element.lower()]
   return index_list```

Comment: @Grebtsew `index` method won't be reliable, because it will always find the first occurrence in the `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a one-time thing or an inner loop?  Just make everything uppercase (or equivalently lower-case).

```
keyword_upper = keyword.upper()
[index for index, element in enumerate(doc_list) if keyword_upper in element.upper()]
```

If you really need speed, then create a regexp pattern out of keyword, and then do a case-insensitive search on each element of the doc_list.